# Conditions Invalid block tag: 'else', expected 'endblock' Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, conditional-statements

```
{% if not User_Tld_Entered  %}
    #HTML HERE

{% endif %}

    {% if User_No_Auth_Tld > 0 %}
        {% for NotAuthDomain in User_No_Auth_Tld %}
            #HTML HERE
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

{% else %}
    {% for tld in tld_set %}
        #HTML HERE
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

For some reason it is failing on the `else` condition above throwing:

```
Invalid block tag: 'else', expected 'endblock'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the `else` supposed to be referring to? Where is the matching `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `{% endif %}` ends the first block. You then have `if User_No_Auth_Tld > 0` and you close that block too. By the time `{% else %}` comes up, you're no longer within an `if` block so it's an unexpected tag.

If you remove the first `{% endif %}` it will work

Comment: While the explanation does make sense, I dont think this will "fix" your issue.

Comment: No problem :) I find a good technique for balancing these blocks in larger pieces of code (since no text editor seems to keep track) is to count the nesting on your fingers: add a finger on each `{% if ... %}` and remove a finger for each `{% endif %}`. If it's all balanced you'll end up with 0. Also, keep your indentation tidy!

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if not User_Tld_Entered  %}
    #HTML HERE

{% endif %} <- this one  needs to go  

    {% if User_No_Auth_Tld > 0 %}
        {% for NotAuthDomain in User_No_Auth_Tld %}
            #HTML HERE
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}   <- or this one nedds to go

{% else %} <-- whos else is this
    {% for tld in tld_set %}
        #HTML HERE
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```